# What's going on with this failed test in Ruby on Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl, and I keep getting this failed test when I run `rails test`

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 68226
Started with run options --seed 29383

 FAIL["test_login_with_remembering", UsersLoginTest, 1.3566609998233616]
 test_login_with_remembering#UsersLoginTest (1.36s)
        Expected: "s0MI7G1uhFcqNFBgQaH9tg"
          Actual: nil
        test/integration/users_login_test.rb:45:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'

  44/44: [===============================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:01, Time: 00:00:01

Finished in 1.36854s
44 tests, 206 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

this is my code:

```
def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
end

test "login with remembering" do
   log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
   @user.reload
   assert_not_nil cookies['remember_token']
   assert_equal cookies['remember_token'], @user.remember_token
end
```

and this is in my users.yml file:

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  admin: true
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
```

It seems like `@user.remember_token` does not hold a value at the time of testing.

Comment: `@user.remember_token` is not being set, or it is not being saved. I can't say more without knowing what `log_in_as` is doing. A link to the tutorial and your `log_in_as` code would help.

Answer (score 0):

The moment you reload the object from persisted, every change applied onto it is lost, unless persisted.

So, in your case, you must either persist or do not reload, before testing the expected values.

```
test "login with remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
    # @user.reload # skip this
    assert_not_nil cookies['remember_token']
    assert_equal cookies['remember_token'], @user.remember_token
end
```